# how to make the backtracking algorithm properly?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an exercise (please take a look at picture):

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx8yB.jpg)

The problem:
You input any number (number is integer) then the program will find numbers in binary tree has 4 levels. The top is your number you input, and the pair of 2 numbers at lower level will be added together and 2 times the parent number above. And the numbers must be used only once.

Here my code, but it still doesn't work properly. Please figure out for me what is my mistake here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 15 
int data[MAX]; // binary tree with 4 levels


void init_Data(){
  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i<=MAX; i++){
    data[i] = -1;
  }
}

void BackTracking(int index){
  int c1, c2; // c1 and c2 are a pair that is added and equal 2 times the parent number
  for(c1=1; c1<data[index]; c1++){
    c2 = 2*data[index] - c1;
    if(!Search(c1) && !Search(c2)){ // checking c1 and c2 is used or not
        data[2*index+1] = c1; // put c1 into data
        data[2*index+2] = c2; // put c2 into data
        if(index == MAX/2) // the stop condition
          print_Data(); // print out 
        else
          BackTracking(index+1);
    }
  }
}

bool Search(int number){
  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    if(number == data[i])
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int n = 0;
  init_Data();

  printf("Enter your number: ");
  scanf("%d\n", &n);
  data[0] = n; 
  BackTracking(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by writing a simple program that accepts the first number from the user. Get that working and then think about how to implement the rest. You might also want to review your notes on recursion.

Comment: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: If you don't even want to write the problem in the question in clear text, instead of linking a photo of a hand-drawn picture, then instead of getting answered you can just expect to get downvotes and the question closed.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to make it clearly.

Comment: Smells like homework to me.  Someone kill this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got working code for this exercise, but since it is an exercise, I'll just give some primers.

**How do you solve the problem?** One way to find a valid configuration (of Sudoku grids, of eight non-attacking queens on a chess board or of numbers in a tree) is [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking): You prober various possible solutions and when you find that it is invalid, you revert to a previous partial solution that is still valid.

One way to implement backtracking is to use recursion, where each step in the solution (put a number in the Sudoku grid, placing a queen, assigning a pait of numbers in your problem) is one level of recursion. Backracking then means to return to previous levels in the recursion.

**How do you represent the tree?** Your picture shows a binary tree. You can represent such a tree as a linear array:

```
                0
        1               2 
    3       4       5       6
  7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
```

For a node with the array index `i`, you get:

```
   parent(i) == (i - 1) / 2
     left(i) == 2*i + 1
    right(i) == 2*i + 2
```

You need the array to print the solution once you have found it.

**How do you traverse the tree?** There are [many ways to traverse a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). Here, you can use many ways as long as you have assigned a value to the parent node before visiting it.

In your case, the easiest way is to do a level-wise iteration that follows the linear array. You can use the fact that the two numbers you need to find for each parant node are adjacent. Start with index `i = 1` and if you can find two valid numbers, advace to `i + 2`.

That way to iterate also provides a nice terminating condition: When you reach the fifth level, you have found a valid solution.

**How do you find out whether a number has been used?** The straightforward solution is to look at all numbers up to the current index. This method will become slow the deeper you go in your tree, though. (But that shouldn't be a concern for a tree of 4 levels.)

If you choose your numbers such that the smaller number if always to the right, you have a binary search tree. You can use that to find whether a number has been used in (O log n), that is you have to visit each level of the tree once instead of visiting each node once.

There are other ways to keep track of which numbers have been used like bit sets or hashes, but these have to be implemented in C.

**Edit**: You've got the basics of the code right, but:

- The termination criterion should be checked for the next step, so `index + 1 == MAX/2`. Alternatively, you can check `index` before (and instead of) entering the loop. (I prefer the latter, because it puts the termination criterion at the top of the function, but the former is closer to your existing code.)
- In `Search`, you check the whole range of elements. That's okay, because the unused elements are −1. There is one problem, though: You don't reset the used elements, so that the check is against values from solutions that you have backtracked from. You can reset these values to −1 before backtracking. A better approach might be to check only the values that you have already entered. (Not resetting the values means that you will find fewer solutions. The first value for which there are solutions is 8, but without resetting, it won't find a solution here.)
- Currently, you print all solutions. (Well, all solutions for which the left bracnch has the smaller number.) Depending on the value, there will be a lot of solutions. If you just want to print one solution, you can stop backtracking short by returning early.
- You should provide prototypes of the functions before you use them, so that the compiler can make sure you are passing the correct arguments.

Here's a corrected version:

```
void BackTracking(int index){
  int c1, c2;
  for(c1=1; c1<data[index]; c1++){
    c2 = 2*data[index] - c1;
    if(!Search(c1) && !Search(c2)){
        data[2*index+1] = c1;
        data[2*index+2] = c2;
        if(index + 1 == MAX/2)
          print_Data();
        else
          BackTracking(index+1);
        data[2*index+1] = -1;
        data[2*index+2] = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. I am trying to code but it still has not worked yet. :). above is my code, please take a look and figure out for me.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You're nearly there. I've updated my post.

Comment: It seems still has problems here. The code looks right but when I run program, it is crashed. Then I debuged, I dont know in processing some strange values suddenly appear. is it because stack is overflow when recursions were called many times?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can solve it using dynamic programming, if you do not care about number of computations, then you can also use combination algorithms.

```
your input = 10
for first level there could be X possible pair of numbers {n1,n2} = 2*10
for each of the pairs above pick one and use recursion to check further

run(input,tree)
  for n1 from 0 to input:
    for n2 from n1+1 to input:
        if n1+n2 = 2*input:
            pairs.add(n,input-n)
  //if no pairs staisfy our condition
  if pairs ==null:
    return false
  //check each pair
  foreach pair in pairs:
    run(pair.numbers, tree)
```

Comment: You can eliminate the second `for` loop by setting `n2 = 2*input - n1` directly And why do you add `(n, input - n)` to the list instead of `(n1, n2)`? As far as I can see, this solution also fails to check the condition that no number must be used more then once in the whole tree and it lacks the termination condition that the tree is 4 levels leep. The principal approach is probably good, though.

Comment: (My criticism aside, it's not my downvote.)

Comment: Probably retribution from OP for not providing a complete, commented, tested copypasta answer in C source.